# My JavaScript redirection code is not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Experiment</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

location.href = "https://www.bing.com";
function rere()
{
location.href = "https://www.google.com";
}

window.onload=function(){setTimeout(rere, 5000);};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do following operations:

1. Go to a Location.
2. Wait until page loading.
3. Then go to a new location.

But, it stacked only at the first location.

Comment: Once you redirect user from your page to another, rest of the scripts loaded on your website will no longer work.

Comment: Comment `// location.href = "https://www.bing.com";` and add *window*.location.href

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because the JavaScript is part of your currently open page. When a new page is loaded, it is stopped. So your Javascript is no longer running, now it's Bing's turn.

You might want to check iframes.